# How to display only the first two elements from ten same elements

Tags: theme-development, css

For example, in my theme, I have the following elements,

```
<ul>
<li> apple </li>
<li> orange </li>
<li> banana </li>
<li> pear </li>
<li> peach </li>
...
</ul>
```

I just want to display the first two *li* elements, how to hide the other ones form the third element?

The given condition to my issue is that, I cannot add any attribute like *id* or *class* to *li* elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can css

```
ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

It'll not show 3rd and up.